# Angular 8 Browser Refresh Result to 401

Tags: angular, angular8

Newbie here.
I am using angular 8 SPA with asp.net core webapi

Here are the scenario.

Scenario 1  usehash=true.

1. When i login to my page basically
   it navigates to the HOME screen and then do a browser refresh
   works fine, if i navigate to other screen and do a browser refresh
   it works fine.

Scenario 2 usehash=false

1. When i login to my page basically
   it navigates to the HOME screen and then do a browser refresh
   works fine,BUT if i navigate to other screen and do a browser refresh
   it says 401 error

So to make the long story short, **when i am not using the usehash=true** i am getting a 401 error
Hope someone could point out where the error is.

Thanks,

pong

Comment: can you please share the web.config file

Comment: i dont' have a the web.config, json.pack

Comment: Which server you are using to host the Angular application?

Comment: IIS or others.?

Comment: localhost, iisexpress

Answer (score 1):

When you use angular routing and deploy to server you should redirect the requests to index.html Check the details here https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration